# How do you make a callable object in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, callable

How do you make a callable type or object in Clojure?

For example, how could I define a record `Foo` taking a single value `:bar` which could be called to print that value?

```
user=> (def foo (Foo. "Hello world"))
user=> (foo)
Hello World
user=> (:bar foo)
"Hello World"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(defrecord Foo [bar]
  clojure.lang.IFn
  (invoke [_] (println bar)))
```

`((Foo. "Hello, world!"))`

`;; => Hello, world!`

`(:bar (Foo. "Hello, world!"))`

`;; => "Hello, world!"`

...Whether doing this is a good idea is another question.

---

[Records implementing IFn](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/496fa19fd7fcce3d)

```
(defrecord Foo [bar]
  clojure.lang.IFn
  (invoke [_] (println bar))
  (applyTo [this args] (clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper this args)))
```

Comment: Why might you not recommend doing this?